# Prevent view from jumping when selection goes off-screen

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using a Word VBA macro to select a certain number of paragraphs backward in my document. However, when the selection moves off-screen, the view jumps to the start of the selection. I want to prevent the view from jumping and maintain my current view in the document.

Here is my macro:

```vb
Sub SelectParagraphsBackward()
    Dim NumParagraphs As Integer
    NumParagraphs = 10 ' Change this number to the desired number of paragraphs to select backward from cursor position
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Turn off screen updating to prevent the view from jumping
    
    For i = 1 To NumParagraphs
        Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Turn on screen updating
End Sub
```

I've tried turning off screen updating with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` as shown in the code above, but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. The view still jumps when the selection moves off-screen.

Is there a way to prevent the view from jumping in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You use `Selection`, so it defaults to scroll the window pane into view.
2. Because using the `MoveUp` method of the object `Selection`, the view of course scrolls to the end of its selection and of course will be the `the start of the selection.` Actually, it is the end of the Selection object, not the start, of this selection process. You said it is the start because you look at them from the top of the selection area with human eyes. However, when we use the `Start` and the `End` property to set a range to read and OP a document, *the Start is always less or smaller or ln front of or equal to the End whatever how or where to start to select the content or set a Range object*. It is just like human intuition.

These are the `Selection` objects logic, before using them, you should try to understand how they work first.

So if you want after selecting done, it still stands along by your starting side, then you should use the  `Range` object to implement and use the method `Select` of the Range to show the Selection effect. Such as:

```vb
Sub SelectParagraphsBackward()
    Dim NumParagraphs As Integer
    NumParagraphs = 10 ' Change this number to the desired number of paragraphs to select backward from cursor position
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection.Range.Duplicate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Turn off screen updating to prevent the view from jumping
   
    For i = 1 To NumParagraphs - 1
'        Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        Set rng = rng.Paragraphs(1).Previous.Range
    Next i

    rng.End = Selection.Start
    rng.Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Turn on screen updating
End Sub
```

Or you just use the `ScrollIntoView` method to restore the view position:

```vb
Sub SelectParagraphsBackward1()
    Dim NumParagraphs As Integer
    NumParagraphs = 10 ' Change this number to the desired number of paragraphs to select backward from cursor position
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Turn off screen updating to prevent the view from jumping
    
    For i = 1 To NumParagraphs
        Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Next i
    
    Selection.Document.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Characters(Selection.Characters.Count), True
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Turn on screen updating
End Sub
```

Eventually, you should understand what's the method `ScreenUpdating`  to do either, before you use them, and not rude in a rush and without patience on it.